# Linux: watch number of files in directory

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to write a shell script that waits until the number of files in a specified directory ( say ~/fit/) has reached a predefined number. What I've got so far is:

```
limit = 10
while [ls ~/fit/ | wc -l -lt $limit]
do
  sleep 1
done
```

This says -lt is an invalid option to wc. I also tried

```
[$limit -gt ls ~/fit/ | wc -l]
```

but it didn't work either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is better place to ask questions like this.

Comment: @atomizer: I don't really think that's true. Shell scripting, as a particular kind of programming, has always been within the scope of SO. While the unix/linux SE site does explicitly mention it in its FAQ, it's still in beta, and its existence doesn't alter the scope of SO.

Comment: A similar question on meta: [should questions about R go on SO or stats.stackexchange.com?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65623/which-site-is-more-reasonable-for-questions-about-r-so-or-stats-stackexchange-co)

Comment: If this is not just a shell learning exercise, you should not poll for changes, but rather tell the system to notify you when a change happens. Linux offers the [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) interface for that; you'd want to use the [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that minimize the use of external processes, like `ls`, `wc` and `true`, and manage correctly the (unusual) case of filenames containing newlines:

```
#!/bin/sh

nmax=10

while :; do
  n=0
  for f in ~/fit/*; do
    n=$((n+1))
  done
  [ $n -ge $nmax ] && break
  sleep 1
done

echo "Limit reached!"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
limit=10
while [ `ls ~/fit/ | wc -l` -lt $limit ];
...
```

Comment: Explanation for the OP: you had two problems. One, you need spaces by the brackets. Two, you need to tell bash that you want it to use command substitution (replace a command with the results of the command); it was simply trying to use all those things as strings. (Side note: you might want to be in the habit of using `$(...)` instead of `\`...\``, since it can be nested.)

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
limit=10
while [ `ls ~/fit/ | wc -l` -lt $limit ]
do
  sleep 1
done
```

Changes:

- There should not be spaces around `=`
  in `limit=10`
- There should be spaces surrounding
  `[` and `]`
- You need to place the command that
  gets you the file count (`ls ~/fit/ |
  wc -l`) in back ticks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`` while(true)
do
var=`ls -l ~/fit/ | wc -l`
  if [ $var -lt 10]
  then
    sleep 1
  else
    break
  fi
done ``